# useEffect throws an error when used to set input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, html-input, use-effect

I'm trying to make an input component that will be controlled by react and that will update it's value whenever a props is changed.

This is how I'm doing it:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Component(props) {
  const [url, setUrl] = React.useState(props.value);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setUrl(props.value);
  }, [props.value]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setUrl(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={url}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Although the logic works I still get an error saying that my component is switching from controlled to uncontrolled, but I don't see why this would be the case.

Comment: Check if initial `props.value` is not `undefined`. Or provide some default `setState(props.value || '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of `useEffect` here. If the parent component's state changes, then the props of the child component will update automatically as it will trigger a rerender. Just remove your `useEffect` code and it should work fine.

Furthermore, I believe this will trigger an infinite loop because each time `url` is updated, it would trigger the `useEffect` hook, which would update the `url`, which would trigger `useEffect` etc.

It would also be a good idea to set a default value on `props.value`:

```js
const [url, setUrl] = React.useState(props.value || '');
```

By the way, I would use `useCallback` for your `handleChange` method.

```js
const handleChange = React.useCallback((event) => setUrl(event.target.value), []);
```

This will memoize the function for better performance.

Comment: All I know is that without the call to useEffect state remains undefined, props.value is provided by react-redux mapStateToProps, could this be the issue ?

Comment: If you're using Redux to manage the state, then you cannot use `useState`. That won't update the state in the Redux store. You have to make an _action creator_ instead of `useState` and update that. Either way, you won't need `useEffect`.

Comment: Nope, i’m not trying to update the redux store through the component, all i’m saying is that when the prop changes the state value doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

change

`const [url, setUrl] = React.useState(props.value);`

to

`const [url, setUrl] = React.useState(props.value || '');`

Because at first `props.value` (and your `url`) will be undefined, and afterwards defined. that means the input field gets converted from uncontrolled to controlled.